# Connection Refused?

Tags: java

I am getting the following exception in my code:
[image]

I cant understand the reason for this exception...

here is my code:
  {

```
import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*;
 class whois {
  public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {
   int c;
   Socket s=new Socket("internic.net",43);
   InputStream in=s.getInputStream();
   OutputStream out=s.getOutputStream();
   String str=(args.length==0 ? "webopedia.com" : args[0])+"\n";
   byte buf[]=str.getBytes();
   out.write(buf);
   while((c=in.read())!=-1) {
    System.out.print((char)c);
   }
    s.close();
   }
  }
 }
```

please tell the reason for this exception.

Comment: If you use an IDE or an editor with run-button, like scite, you get the output in a nice window, where you can grab it with the mouse, no need to make a screenshot for text output.

Comment: I think even the windows shell allows copy+paste of text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In brief: you can't connect with `internic.net` on port 43 from your current client. Either the server port ist not available, your firewall blocks traffic or your client can't resolve the symbolic name of the server.

Comment: +1: Failing to resolve the address at all would give a different error. If it resolves the address incorrectly, you could get this error.  I tried to telnet myself don't believe this service is running on this server (or you cannot access it)

Comment: then what should be the port number??

Comment: How would he know? What service are you trying to access?

Answer (score 6):

I did a bit of digging around.  Port 43 is the WHOIS service, and it seems that you should be using "whois.internic.net" as the hostname for the Internic instance of the WHOIS service.

---

I'm currently getting "No route to host" for whois.internic.net ...

My conclusion is that the host and/or services at whois.internic.net are unreliable at the moment.  I suggest that you use the search form at "http://internic.net/whois.html" instead.

---

The search form above gives no information for "www.webopedia.com" ... because it *has* no information about that domain!  But it DOES have information about "webopedia.com".  That makes sense to me:

- "webopedia.com" is the primary domain name that is registered with some domain registrar and served by the ".com" DNS servers.  It has WHOIS information.
- "www.webopedia.com" is a subdomain whose DNS information is served by the people who run "webopedia.com"; see above.

This is all confirmed by looking at the DNS records for the two names.  Use `dig` or the equivalent Windows tool to look at the DNS records.

In short, your program is telling the truth ... when it works.

Comment: Now my program does not give exception.But for any url(webopedia.com) in this case,it says No Match for:www.webopedia.com          why is this so?